# How to close show button on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $p = $('div.striker');

  $("#show").click(function(){
    $p.css('overflow', 'visible');

  });
});
```

How to close on click buton ???

HTML

```
 <div class="striker">
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
           If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.

           </div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by close? did you mean hide?

Comment: Use css property " Display:none ",to hide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to hide on clicking on this show button use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var $p = $('div.striker');

      $("#show").click(function(){
        $p.hide();

      });
    });
```

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/31/

If you want to switch display when clicking in the show button.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $p = $('div.striker');

  $("#show").click(function(){
    $p.toggle();

  });
});
```

It will hide if it is displaying striker content and it will display striker content if its hide.

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/32/

Answer (score 1):

Change js to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $p = $('div.striker');

  $("#show").click(function(){
   $p.css('display', 'none');
   // or $p.hide();

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
`$p.css('overflow', 'visible');`
```

Try:

```
$p.css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

For hiding show button

```
 $("#show").click(function(){
    $p.css('overflow', 'visible');
    $(this).hide();  //  or $(this).css('display','none');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these two options:

```
$p.css('visibility', 'hidden');`
```

This will hide the button but the space used is remain used.

```
$p.css('display', 'none');
```

This will hide the button and the space where the button previously appears is also released.

space - The region where the button is displayed.